# Botman Telegram

Tags: bots, telegram-bot

they could help me I do not know how to put buttons in telegram, only in facebook messenger, where the error can be ?

```
$botman->hears('1', function ($bot) {
  $bot->reply("• Android versión 4.4.2 (KitKat) o superior
• Espacio en memoria de almacenamiento
• Memoria RAM superior a 1 GB
• Duración de batería superior a 12 horas de uso continuo
• Conexión a red celular 3G o superior
• Conexión a Internet");

$bot->reply('¿ Algo más en lo que pueda ayudarte ?')
->addButton(Button::create('Tell a joke')
)
->addButton(Button::create('Give me a fancy quote')
)

});
```

Comment: You need isolate the problem and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a clear explanation of what isn't working with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved using the classes of app / Conversations.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Conversations;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Incoming\Answer;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Outgoing\Question;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Outgoing\Actions\Button;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Conversations\Conversation;

class ExampleConversation extends Conversation
{
    /**
     * First question
     */
    public function askReason()
    {
        $question = Question::create("Huh - you woke me up. What do you need?")
            ->fallback('Unable to ask question')
            ->callbackId('ask_reason')
            ->addButtons([
                Button::create('Tell a joke')->value('joke'),
                Button::create('Give me a fancy quote')->value('quote'),
            ]);

        return $this->ask($question, function (Answer $answer) {
            if ($answer->isInteractiveMessageReply()) {
                if ($answer->getValue() === 'joke') {
                    $joke = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random'));
                    $this->say($joke->value->joke);
                } else {
                    $this->say(Inspiring::quote());
                }
            }
        });
    }
                     //clases dinamicas, cambiar estructura de base de datos  :v
    /**
     * Start the conversation
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->askReason();
    }
}
```

and in your botman.php :

```html
$botman->hears('/start', function (BotMan $bot) {
    $bot->startConversation(new ExampleConversation());
});
```